# Crystal Reports Chart Detail Suppression

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have multiple entries each which can have one or more approval stages (with a date).  I've been able to use grouping/detail suppression to only retrieve the latest approval stage (as we don't care if it was submitted if it's currently final approval) but no matter what I try the chart always shows every single record which brings back information we don't need to see.

Does anyone know how to fix this chart so that it only brings back the latest approval stage for each entry (with multiple approval stages)?

[image](http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/8030/screenshot20130411at302.png) (can't post images yet)

Comment: Offtopic, but can't you create view(s) in database, allowing to query required data (latest stages) directly? From my experience it is much easier to create specific views and use them than make Crystal behave as required :)

Comment: Yeah, that may be an alternative solution.  Still would rather solve the report as it is as I feel like I'm so close just the chart isn't displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

Charts, like cross-tabs, act on all of the data in the report.  You will need to build the report in a way that the extraneous data is removed.

I would recommend using a SQL-expression field to identify the latest approval stage, then reference this field in the record-selection formula.  See my posting: [Crystal Reports: Using SQL Expression Fields](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/07/crystal-reports-using-sql-expression-fields/).

If the syntax is unruly, you can always use a Command.